# How to use WHERE and GROUP BY together in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have simple MySQL table where I want to run MySQL syntax with WHERE and GROUP BY conditions.

MySQL Table:

```
sender    destination   message
| a |     | b        |  |  ..  |
| b |     | a        |  |  ..  |
| a |     | b        |  |      |
| a |     | b        |  |      |
| b |     | a        |  |      |
```

In this context, I have 3 messages for me if I am 'b'

```
SELECT * FROM table where destination = 'b';
```

But I have only sender i.e 'a'

Hence, I want result as '1' message meant for me but count in terms of sender.

Code to be corrected.

```
SELECT * FROM table where destination = 'b' GROUP BY sender;
```

Here I want 1 as result because 'b' have only one sender that is 'a'. If I have two different senders it must be 2

Comment: Edit your question and include the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the count of the result as follows. Hope this helps you

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct FROM table WHERE destination='b' GROUP BY sender;
```

Comment: here I want 1 as result becuase 'b' have only one sender. If I have two different senders it must be 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are expecting as a result.

Try this query. You've receive sender and count of 'b' destintations:

```
SELECT sender, count(*) AS cnt FROM table where destination='b' GROUP BY sender;
```

Comment: here I want 1 as result becuase 'b' have only one sender. If I have two different senders it must be 2

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM table_name WHERE destination='b' GROUP BY sender
```

OR to skip the nulls

```
SELECT COUNT(message) AS CNT FROM table_name WHERE destination=b GROUP BY sender
```